# Hiding HTML Element With Specific Class Unless URL Parameter is Present Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, getelementsbyclassname

Trying to hide an element (class of "input-container") with a specific class unless a specific URL parameter is present. Have worked out the following code, but can't seem to get it to work. The if/else statement has been tested using alerts, so I know that portion is working. It's where I'm trying to assign the display variable where the code seems to be breaking. Unfortunately, I have to do this using the class name rather than an ID. Thoughts?

```
<script>
  var isadmin = document.getElementsByClassName("input-container");
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('admin=yes') > -1) {
    isadmin[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    isadmin[0].style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at (index):57
(anonymous) @ (index):57

Comment: That means that your element collection returned from `document.getElementsByClassName("input-container")` is empty. Can you debug it and check ? Did you spell the class name wrongly ?

Comment: Just triple-checked and it's correct. It works when I copy/paste that class name and hide the element with straight CSS. Additionally, I tried it with different class names and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was an issue between the seat and the keyboard. I'm an idiot and didn't realize that the Javascript was executing prior to the elements loading. Fixed the issue with the following code...

```
<script>
  window.onload = hidePass;
  function hidePass() {
  var isadmin = document.getElementsByClassName('input-container')[0]; 
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('admin=yes') > -1) {
    isadmin.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    isadmin.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems alright. I wonder why is not working. Anyway I would try this

```
<script>
  var isadmin = document.getElementsByClassName("input-container");
  var url = new URL(window.location);
  if (url.searchParams('test') && url.searchParams('test') == 'yes') {
    isadmin[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    isadmin[0].style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Using the code you provided gives me the following error:
(index):55 Uncaught TypeError: url.searchParams is not a function
    at (index):55
(anonymous) @ (index):55

Regardless, the parameter search isn't the issue... I've tested it with alerts. It's the assigning of the display CSS that where it's breaking.